# SQL Syntax, H2-Database & Intellij-Idea - colums and table names to lowercase

Tags: sql, intellij-idea

I am using database plugin from Intellij Idea 13.1.4 with H2 as db and SQL as dialect. Always when I try to create a table the Intellij Idea will put all table attributes to uppercase. Tried Intellij Idea > Preferences > Code Style > SQL > Wordcase > Keywords > "do not change" but nothing has changed, it still puts my code when executed to uppercase.

Photo: http://postmyimage.com/img2/161_Screen_Shot_2014_09_24_at_23.2.png

Any ideas?

Thanks!!

Comment: I've just tried this, and have no problems at all. Are you using a beta, or did you report your version number incorrectly? If it's a beta, maybe it's just broken and you should report a defect.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. No, as far as I know 13.1.4 is not a beta version. What version are you using?

Comment: 13.1.4 - your question says something different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the solution:

http://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/constant/DbSettings.html#DATABASE_TO_UPPER

> This class contains various database-level settings. To override the
>   documented default value for a database, append the setting in the
>   database URL: "jdbc:h2:test;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=FALSE" when opening the
>   first connection to the database. The settings can not be changed once
>   the database is open.